# UIAutomation UICollectionView cell cannot be tapped

Tags: javascript, ios, uicollectionview, tap

I am trying to implement a UIAutomation script as follows:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();    
var window = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow();
var collectionView = window.collectionViews()[0];
collectionView.cells()[0].tap();
```

When I run the script I get the following in the log:

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().collectionViews()[0].cells()[0].tap()
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().collectionViews()[0].cells()[0].scrollToVisible()

Script threw an uncaught javascript error: t...cells()[0] could not be tapped
```

If I call this on any other cell it works but for some reason the first one doesn't. Anyone out there encountered this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I've been experiencing the same thing. If you use Instruments-> Automation to record a new script you'll see that it generally does a `.tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:0.15, y:0.35}})`, not an object `.tap()`.

I'm not sure what your display structure is, but the app I'm testing has collection views in cells of a collection view. While `target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().collectionViews()[0].cells()[0].collectionViews()[0].cells()[0]` works `target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().collectionViews()[0].cells()[1].collectionViews()[0].cells()[0]` does not, `target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().collectionViews()[0].cells()[1].collectionViews()[0].tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:0.17, y:0.42}})` works, but I'd rather `.cells()[0]` worked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Would up vote but don't have the rep ;)